# Run from a validator node

Tags: solana-program

I would like to know what I could do to run a node and be a validator on Solana.

I know that there are hardware requirements to run a validator node, but I also know that there are cloud solutions dedicated to this. I would like to know the best way, I can invest a sum to run this node, but I needed this guidance (whether it is better to build a computer, or run something in the cloud).

Answer (score 1):

In general its always better to run your own hardware. It will be cheaper and better performance and you have full control.

There is however a solution how to run a validator in the cloud in aws:

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-blockchain-node-runners

Which was presented at the last breakpoint conference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wqADZnNPSV0&ab_channel=Solana